# SQL: how to select common lines of one table on several column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, rows

I have a table :

```
create table a (page int, pro int)
go
insert into a select 1, 2
insert into a select 4, 2
insert into a select 5, 2
insert into a select 9, 2
insert into a select 1, 3
insert into a select 2, 3
insert into a select 3, 3
insert into a select 4, 3
insert into a select 9, 3
insert into a select 1, 4
insert into a select 9, 4
insert into a select 12, 4
insert into a select 1, 5
insert into a select 9, 5
insert into a select 12, 5
insert into a select 13, 5
insert into a select 14, 5
insert into a select 15, 5
go
```

(here is the [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/782a5/12) of this table and queries I began to write )

### Common value of page on ALL lines

1. I'm looking to extract the **common column** "page" for each column "pro" from this table.
   here is what we expect :

   ```
    1
    9
   ```

   I tried to use:

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT a.page
   FROM a
   WHERE a.page IN (
     SELECT b.page FROM a as b
     WHERE b.pro <> a.pro
   )
   ```

   but this query returns every "page" that have **at least** one common values which is not what we need to have. see below :

   ```
    1
    4
    9
   12
   ```

   The opposite query aka different value at least one but not all time
2. I'm looking to extract the "page" linked to one or more "pro" but without being common to all of them (it's the exact opposite of the previous query)

Here is what we expect :

```
  2
  3
  4
  5
 12
 13
 14
 15
```

I can't manage to find a solution to those 2 queries :'( 
Could anyone help me on those ones?

Best regards

edit: the SQLfiddle url

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a bit of reversed thinking - group by `page` and count distinct `pro` values for each. Return rows that matches the total of distinct `pro` values

```
SELECT [page]
FROM a
GROUP BY [page]
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pro) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT pro) FROM a)
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/782a5/21)**

EDIT: for the second problem, just replace `=` with '<' in the final line -> **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/782a5/27)**

Answer (score 1):

Fot the first part of the question, try this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.page FROM a t1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t2.pro) FROM a t2 WHERE
       t2.page = t1.page) = 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t3.pro) FROM a t3)
```

---

And the second query is the simple substraction from all page values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t4.page FROM a t4
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT t1.page FROM a t1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t2.pro) FROM a t2 WHERE
       t2.page = t1.page) = 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t3.pro) FROM a t3)
```

Comment: `EXCEPT` keyword doesn't work on SQL server 2000 but i see the logic in it.

Comment: Sorry, tried on Fiddle, and it worked, so i suggested that it worsk on target DB :)

Comment: no problem, i've managed to change it for sql server 2000 as following : 
    SELECT DISTINCT t4.page
    FROM  a as t4
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT t1.page FROM a as t1
                        WHERE (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t2.pro) FROM a as t2 WHERE
                           t2.page = t1.page) = 
                    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t3.pro) FROM a as t3)
                    AND t4.page = t1.page AND t1.pro = t4.pro
)
see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/782a5/33