# Inner join same multiple times based on input

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation like below:

```
  PlanID  StateID

    1   22
    2   22
    2   30
    3   7
    3   22
    3   33
    3   46
    4   22
    5   22
    12  22
    13  7
    13  22
    13  30
    13  33
    13  40
    13  46
    14  22
    15  7
    15  20
    15  22
    15  30
    15  33
    15  40
    15  46
    16  22
    17  7
    17  20
    17  22
    17  30
    17  40
```

Now when user send stateID from UI to sql query I need to find the common PlanIDs as out put.I dont know how many stateID will be sent from UI(because it is completely depending on checkbox list selection of user)

so if user send 22 and 7 then o/p should be 3,13,15,17
if user send 22,20,7  then o/p should be 15,17

Query i have got so far is :

```
select a.*, b.* from 

 Plan_State a
 Inner join Plan_State b
 ON a.PlanID = b.PlanID

WHERE 
    (
        a.StateID =22
    ) AND 
    (
        b.StateID=7
    )
```

But what if user send more than 2 stateIDs. And one small note is, my stateID list in coming in as a string(Like 22,7,20)

Thanks

Comment: so if they send 3 state ids, you need to join 3 ways for `a=22 and b=7 and c=20`? 4 states would be `a=?/b=?/c=?/d=?` ?

Comment: Yes,but how to write the dynamic query based on input?

Comment: What is inbetween your UI and the query? Isn't there some programming language that can build a dynamic query for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query gets all plans that match as many different states as there are in the IDs passed. `<IDS>` is the list of ids, which is used twice in the query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  PlanID
FROM
  YourTable t
WHERE
  t.StateID in (<IDS>)
GROUP BY
  PlanID
HAVING
  COUNT('x') = 
    ( SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT StateId) 
      FROM 
        YourTable st
      WHERE
        st.StateID IN (<IDS>) )
```

All you have to do is insert the list of IDS in the query, so it could look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  PlanID
FROM
  YourTable t
WHERE
  t.StateID in (1, 2, 5)
GROUP BY
  PlanID
HAVING
  COUNT('x') = 
    ( SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT StateId) 
      FROM 
        YourTable st
      WHERE
        st.StateID IN (1, 2, 5) )
```

No quotes, no splitting (unless you want to do some input validation/sanitation).

You could remove the subselect if you are able to parse the input and determine the number of different IDs in there. It might be a bit faster.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a variable number of states coming in, then don't use the join method. It'll quickly get out of control. I'd suggest something more like:

```
SELECT PlanID, COUNT(stateID) AS count
FROM yourtable
WHERE (stateID IN (x,x,x,x,x))
GROUP BY PlanID
HAVING count = ($number_of_states_being_searched_for)
```

You'd still have to count up how many states you're looking for, but this will still be a much cheaper query than doing `N` self-joins.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT PlanID  
FROM this_table
GROUP BY PlanID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT StateID) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT StateID) FROM this_table)
```

If you need common for all PlanIDs,
[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469739/sql-how-to-select-common-lines-of-one-table-on-several-column/17469869#17469869)

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic query could do the trick for you.

Pass the stateID list as comma separated parameter to the procedure. then build the dynamic query as

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQL = "SELECT PLANID FROM [table] WHERE STATEID = " + (SELECT REPLACE(@arg,","," AND STATEID = ");
```

Comment: How many values can `STATEID` have in a single row?  I think you still need some aggregation.